# Почему в MinGW иногда срабатывает автообнуление неинициализированных переменных?

Tags: оптимизация, g++, mingw, неопределённое-поведение

Работаю в Windows 7, среда Code::Blocks 16.01, рекомендуемая по-дефолту на их сайте версия с MinGW.

Есть несколько крайне похожих примера кода:

```
#include <iostream>

void bar()
{
    int a;
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;
    return;
}

void foo()
{
    int a = 3;
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Выводимые адреса на моей машине совпадают в 100% случаев, и это вполне понятное поведение.

```
#include <iostream>

void bar()
{
    int a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return;
}

void foo()
{
    int a = 3;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

А вот здесь начинаются странности. Если включена любая оптимизация, то выводит:

> 3
>
> 0

а если их убрать, то выводится:

> 3
>
> 3

На таком примере кода:

```
#include <iostream>

void bar()
{
    int a;
    std::cout << a << " " << &a << std::endl;
    return;
}

void foo()
{
    int a = 3;
    std::cout << a << " " << &a << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

> 3 <адрес>
>
> 3 <адрес>

выводится всегда, вне зависимости от флагов оптимизации.

Почему включение флагов оптимизации так избирательно влияет на автообнуление переменных?

К слову, при использовании g++ из-под Ubuntu 14.04 были получены аналогичные результаты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое поведение оптимизатора связано с тем, что в первом случае переменная не используется и её можно удалить, а в третьем случае нужен её адрес и удалить переменную нельзя.

Comment: Это не очень хорошее объяснение. В присутствии UB компилятор имел право убрать и обе переменные, и адрес. И чем более продвинутый оптимизатор у вашего компилятора, тем более охотно он будет «ломать» код, обнаружив UB. То, что он в данном случае этого не сделал — ничем не гарантированная случайность.

Comment: Почитайте, например, это: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633.

Comment: @VladD, Спасибо, этот пример я уже видел в комментах на хабре. Я думаю что поведение одинаковых версий компилятора на одинаковых примерах кода и одинаковых платформах всё же будет одинаковым. Эта случайность вносится не языком (ибо у нас тут UB), а самим компилятором. В данном вопросе мне нужно было получить объяснение поведения компилятора при UB (т.е. когда стандарт ничего не говорит), и это объяснение (не моё) единственное которое я смог получить.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что в зависимости от чего угодно (порядка функций в программе, длины строк, текущей даты, ...) результат имеет право отличаться, т. к. всё это может косвенно повлиять на решения, принимаемые оптимизатором. Гарантию типа «если есть взятие адреса, можно спокойно не инициализировать переменную» могут дать вам **только разработчики компилятора**.

Comment: Да, а ещё предположение о том, что в скомпилированном коде каждая функция существует в единственном экземпляре (а следовательно, два вызова функции будут обладать одинаковым поведением), неверно. Подумайте сами, почему.

Answer (score 2):

Это UB. Этот код имеет полное право отформатировать ваш жесткий диск или начать ядерную войну.

Comment: А за что минус? Это и правда UB, и полагаться на то, что «ну какое-то значение же там будет» просто неверно.

Comment: @VladD, никто не отрицает UB. Однако я прошу вас пояснить вторую часть вашего высказывания.

Comment: @hunter: Ну, присутствии UB рассуждение о том, что есть переменная и есть её значение неверно, стандарт в этом случае не гарантирует _вообще ничего_.

Comment: @hunter можно собрать компилятор, который при попытке доступа к такой переменной будет форматировать жёсткий диск, и это не будет противоречить стандарту С++.

Comment: @D-side, да, причём что-то подобное уже было.

Comment: @VladD, вопрос то не про стандарт.

Comment: @hunter: Ну, а вы думаете, что конкретный компилятор гарантирует что-то конкретное в случае UB? Иногда такое и правда бывает для _некоторых_ случаев (например, gcc доопределяет signed overflow), но в обычном случае нет.

Comment: @VladD, ну компилятор всё же детерминированная программа. Можно конечно заполнять неинициализировнные данные содержимым /dev/random, однако в данном конкретном случае этого не происходит (в вопросе я этого не отметил, однако результаты разных выводов программы обладали статистической устойчивостью).

Comment: @hunter: Компилятор-то детерминирован. Но компилирует он не построчно, а _всю программу целиком_, поэтому детерминированность компилятора снова-таки ничего не даёт.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, в С/С++ стандартах нет автообнуления переменных, и непроинициализированные переменные хранят в себе значение, которое содержалось в ячейке памяти до объявления переменной. То, что там хранятся нули, может быть результатом обнуления памяти при завершении предыдущей программой, занимающей данный участок памяти. Не исключено,что оптимизатор компилятора занимается обнулением переменных. Однако хорошей практикой считается инициализировать все переменные сразу при их создании, а отсутствие таковой не гарантирует никакой автоинициализации.

Comment: "Не исключено,что оптимизатор компилятора занимается обнулением переменных." -- почему же он во втором случае обнулил переменные, а в третьем нет?

Comment: @hunter, видимо, у компилятора были на то свои причины. В данном случае не стоит полагаться на конкретное поведение, а просто всегда явно инициализировать переменные.